# How to remove fringe when copying from emacs?

Tags: font-lock, fringe

When copying from emacs buffers in a terminal to other application,

I grab the region and copy them and paste it onto another application.

The copied text has a leading whitespace in each line although emacs has no whitespace when editing.

I think the space is due to `fringe`.

I don't want to turn off fringe, I just want to ignore the fringe when copying, is it possible?

Comment: I don't see this and I very much doubt that the fringe causes it.